# Drawing on an existing image

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, awt

I am writing a program where each line of my painting is dependent on the painting of the previous line. As the new painting requires the RGB values of the previous line at specified coordinates, I convert the JPanel into a BufferedImage and then use getRGB() to get the Color.

I am having an issue with carrying forward the initial image when I am making the image for the new line.

The following code does not work-

```
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(line==1)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(25,25,20,20);
        }
        else if(line!=1)
        {
            g=img.getGraphics();
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillRect(50,50,25,25);
        }
    }
```

Where line is an instance variable and img is the BufferedImage of the first line-

```
Paint_Test ob=new Paint_Test();
frame.add(ob);
img=toBufferedImage(ob);
```

By the line

```
  g=img.getGraphics();
```

I am attempting to get the graphics object of the original bufferedimage and draw onto it. Instead, all I get in the output is a blank screen (The ideal output would be two squares, one red and one blue).

Please let me know where I am going wrong and how I can fix this. Your help would be greatly be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mcve], also you can rewrite the `else if (line!=1)` line to just `else`

Answer (score 0):

There are two common approaches for incremental painting:

1. paint to a BufferedImage and then draw the image
2. keep an ArrayList of objects to paint. Then you iterate through the ArrayList and paint all objects.

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for more information and working examples of each approach.

Answer (score 0):

Camickr's answer is great if you're looking to go explore the topic further. If you're looking for a quick fix go no further-

Instead of *assigning* the graphics object to the image I should have merely drawn the image-

```
g.drawImage(img,0,0,null);
```

This produces the desired result.